# Liquibase Rollback on a Unique Constraint

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I create a changeset to add a unique constraint:

```
- changeSet:
  id: gabe_changeset_01
  changes:
  - addUniqueConstraint:
      columnNames: SUBJECT_TYPE_ID, SUBJECT_NAME
      constraintName: uk_subject_type_name
      tableName: SUBJECT
```

When the unique constraint contains a foreign key column I get an error during the Liquibase [rollback](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-rollback.html).

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot drop index
>   'uk_subject_type_name': needed in a foreign key constraint [Failed
>   SQL: ALTER TABLE SUBJECT DROP KEY uk_subject_type_name]

To get around this I add the following `- rollback`.

```
  - rollback:  
    - dropForeignKeyConstraint:
        baseTableName: SUBJECT
        constraintName: fk_subject_type_id
    -  dropUniqueConstraint:  
        constraintName:  uk_subject_type_name
        tableName:  SUBJECT
    - addForeignKeyConstraint:
        constraintName: fk_subject_type_id
        baseTableName: SUBJECT
        baseColumnNames: SUBJECT_TYPE_ID
        referencedTableName: SUBJECT_TYPE
        referencedColumnNames: ID
        onDelete: RESTRICT
```

The `- addForeignKeyConstraint` is copied from a previous changeset run in the past. This solution feels like an antipattern because I'm breaking the following suggested best practice:

### [One change per changeset](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/bestpractices.html#one-change-per-changeset)

> As far as possible, Avoid multiple changes
>   per changeset to avoid failed auto-commit statements that can leave
>   the database in an unexpected state.

The foreign key constraint worked well before I added the unique constraint, but after I add the unique constraint, it seems to be directly tied to the foreign key preventing me from deleting it.

Is there a solution where I don't need to do this workaround? It would be optimal if I could just rely on Liquibase's auto rollback without defining my own. Maybe there's something in MySQL I can set to get around this?